# The name of a cleveref reference is missing when the reference is inside a subsubsection of an appendix

Tags: sectioning, counters, appendices, cleveref

The following KOMA-Script/LuaLaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}\label{sub}
\cref{sub}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}\label{subsub}
\cref{subsub}
\end{document}
```

prints thus:

[image: A clever reference with a missing name]

Notice that the name of the reference in the subsubsection is missing, unlike the reference in the subsection.

If I increase the number argument for `\setcounter` (say, to `6`, or `10`), the output is the same. However, if I comment out the line `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` altogether, the problem resolves:

[image: When the setcounter line is commented out, the problem resolves]

Why is it? Is there a way to solve the problem without commenting out the `\setcounter` line? The reason why I don't want to comment out the `\setcounter` line, is because in my actual document (not the sample one listed above), this line serves some purpose (though I'm not sure what this purpose is).

Comment: As samcarter's answer shows, the problem is that `subsubsubappendix` (`subsubsection` on an appendix level) has no `cref` string definition. If you remove the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` and let it fall back to the default (`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`?) the `\subsubsection` is not numbered and so both `\label`s refer to the same thing, namely the `\subsection` (the purpose of `secnumdepth` is to control which levels of sectioning get numbered). So the issue would still be there in the last example it just is not visible.

Comment: The issue is not KOMA-Script related. You will get the same issue with a standard class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a definition for the 4th appendix level:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\Crefname{subsubsubappendix}{Appendix}{Appendices}%


\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}\label{sub}
\cref{sub}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}\label{subsub}
\cref{subsub}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One question, though. Why the capital `C` in `\Crefname`? Can I use `\crefname` instead?

Comment: @EvanAad If only one of `\cnameref` or `\Cnameref` is defined cleverref automatically defines the other one as the lower/uppercase variant of it, so it should not really make any difference as long as your names start with normal letters. To be on the save side, you can define both.

Comment: @EvanAad If you decide to define `\cnameref` you should give the lower case name.